# How to update a DynamoDB table from AWS Glue? (pyspark)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am able to write to the table using
`glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options`

However this overwrites the table and looking through the documentation I can't see a way to update it? I have two separate pipelines that I would like to write into the same table from AWS Glue, but as of now they are both overwriting eachother.